# d3.js & nvd3.js axis and label precision formatting

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Using the stacked area chart as seen in this example
http://nvd3.com/ghpages/stackedArea.html

Trying to format the y-axis tick labels and the tooltip labels to be integers instead of floats. Tried changing the follow code from

```
chart.yAxis
        .axisLabel('Users')
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
```

to

```
chart.yAxis
        .axisLabel('Users')
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.0d'));
```

Precision remains unchanged (still shows values to the hundredths place). I've followed the Github Wiki to no avail https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#wiki-d3_format

Any suggestions or hints will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like [this isn't supported by nvd3](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/97) at the moment.  See the offending [line](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/stackedAreaChart.js#L133).

In addition, your format specification isn't quite right. As mentioned in the documentation, `"d"` ignores non-integer values. So you probably want `",.0f"` instead, which means:

- `,`: use commas to separate thousands.
- `.0`: *precision* of zero (the exact meaning of this depends on which *type* is in use).
- `f`: The *type*; in this case, [Number.toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). This means a fixed number of digits (the *precision*) appear after the decimal point, and the number is rounded if necessary.

Comment: Should other people find it useful. I've made a small tutorial on the d3 formatter here with examples: http://koaning.github.io/html/d3format.html

Answer (score 4):

this one can format label text from float to integer.

for pie chart:

`chart.pie.valueFormat(d3.format(',.0d'));`

for line chart:

```
chart.yAxisTickFormat(d3.format(',.0d'));
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.tickFormat` method on the `.yAxis` method doesn't update it properly. This is the work around I used:

```
        chart.yAxisTickFormat(d3.format(',.0d'));
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried like this

```
.axisLabel('%').tickFormat(function(d) { return parseFloat(d).toFixed(1) + "%"; });
```

Its working for me.I am getting results with decimal points and percentage.